# Hide Actionbar, Show Options Menu

Tags: android, android-menu

I have a non-market app that was built to run on a specific device. Originally, this was on a device running 2.2, but now the app is targeting a specific device on 3.1 and I am adding in support for the `Action Bar`.

One of the apps Activities is required to be full-screen and have hidden the status bar and the Action Bar. This is achieved using the following in the manifest:

```
<activity 
    android:name=".activity.EditorActivity"
    android:label="@string/activity_edit"
    android:theme="@style/Canvas">
```

Which references this style:

```
<style name="Canvas" parent="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/bg_white</item>
</style>
```

So, after moving to 3.1, the effect works, in that the `Activity` is fullscreen, and everything is hidden as needed, but this of course hides the options menu from populating the `Action Bar`.

I know that if I leave the `android:targetSdkVersion="8"`, the options menu is shown in the bottom navigation, but this seems like a bit of a hack - is there any other way or 'best practice' for this? I basically have to set `android:targetSdkVersion="12"` to ensure the app works and isn't put onto older devices so this won't be a permanent solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've decided to stop trying to swim upstream and have switched to using a translucent Action Bar that is overlaid - it works perfectly and is exactly what I had been doing prior to 3.x with my custom solution.

[Custom Translucent Android ActionBar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6749261/custom-translucent-android-actionbar)