# Use options menu without action bar

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm am using this to hide the action-/titlebar in my android application

```
this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

I created my options menu with this:

```
MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
inflater.inflate(R.menu.bottom_menu, menu);
return(super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu));
```

And this is the bottom_menu.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+id/refresh"
        android:title="Neu laden" />
    <item android:id="@+id/settings"
        android:title="Einstellungen" />
    <item android:id="@+id/logout"
        android:title="Ausloggen" />
</menu>
```

When I press the menu button, the app crashes. When I don't hide the action-/titlebar, everything works fine.
I already found this question on SO, but I don't solve the Problem: [Hide Actionbar, Show Options Menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8585745/hide-actionbar-show-options-menu)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found the problem myself, stupid...

I changed:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
```

to

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
```