# Set Actionbar overlay mode at runtime in Android

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

How do I set the `actionbar` mode at runtime to not-overlay or overlay with the content at runtime? I tried using `getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTIONBAR_OVERLAY)` but it doesn't allow to set the mode after calling `setContentView()`. This can be done, as I have seen it being done in the Youtube app.

Comment: Hi Sowrabh, did you find any solution?

Comment: No luck @Wayne. The best I could do is to set the actionbar overlay mode to `Window.FEATURE_ACTIONBAR_OVERLAY` always and then set the Y-coordinate of the whole view to the bottom of the actionbar when needed. Not a very clean solution though

Comment: Oh thanks you, that may be a workaround :D. But it will be nice if we know how Youtube did it :D

Comment: [Possible duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6749261/420015)

Comment: That question doesn't ask about changing the actionbar overlay mode at runtime. All it asks is how to get an actionbar in a full screen app.

Comment: I'm pretty sure YouTube is faking us out, and on the 'full screen' video, they have a fake `ActionBar` (totally guessing based on what I am seeing).  On your phone, if you go into landscape and minimize the video, then slowly drag the video to full screen, when the top of it hits the actionbar the actionbar hides / animates up.

Answer (score 5):

Although not necessarily exactly what you're looking for, one decent workaround would be to create a spacer view at the top of the content that is the same height as the ActionBar (android:layout_height="?android:actionBarSize"). When you want overlay mode enabled, set the spacer's visibility to View.GONE, when you want it disabled, set it to View.VISIBLE.

Comment: This is definitely a valid work-around.  The overlay-ness of the ActionBar is a style, and those have to be set before they are shown and don't change at runtime, so a work-around seems necessary.  An issue with this work around is that getting the height of the actionbar isn't as simple as stated in the answer, you have to `getActionBar().getHeight()` after it's visible because the "stacked" actionbar (think actionbar tabs on a phone in portrait) isn't included in android:actionBarSize and because we don't know all the variables Android uses to decide whether or not stacked is shown : (