# android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: requestFeature() must be called before adding content

Tags: java, android

I am getting this `android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: requestFeature() must be called before adding content` error.  As you can see in the below code, the `requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);` line comes before `setContentView(R.layout.mainmenu);` line of code.  This onCreate() code is the same format in just about every one of my activities and I've never had trouble with it before until now.  Ever since I updated to ADT 22 a lot of random errors have been popping up everywhere.  I have weeded through a lot of those errors and this is my latest one.

What can I do to fix this error?

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.mainmenu);
```

LogCat

```
05-31 04:20:43.121: E/AndroidRuntime(14559): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-31 04:20:43.121: E/AndroidRuntime(14559): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{matt.lyons.bibletrivia.lite/matt.lyons.bibletrivia.lite.MainMenu}: android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: requestFeature() must be called before adding content
05-31 04:20:43.121: E/AndroidRuntime(14559):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
05-31 04:20:43.121: E/AndroidRuntime(14559):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
05-31 04:20:43.121: E/AndroidRuntime(14559):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
05-31 04:20:43.121: E/AndroidRuntime(14559):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
05-31 04:20:43.121: E/AndroidRuntime(14559):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-31 04:20:43.121: E/AndroidRuntime(14559):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-31 04:20:43.121: E/AndroidRuntime(14559):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
05-31 04:20:43.121: E/AndroidRuntime(14559):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-31 04:20:43.121: E/AndroidRuntime(14559):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-31 04:20:43.121: E/AndroidRuntime(14559):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
05-31 04:20:43.121: E/AndroidRuntime(14559):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
05-31 04:20:43.121: E/AndroidRuntime(14559):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-31 04:20:43.121: E/AndroidRuntime(14559): Caused by: android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: requestFeature() must be called before adding content
05-31 04:20:43.121: E/AndroidRuntime(14559):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.requestFeature(PhoneWindow.java:229)
05-31 04:20:43.121: E/AndroidRuntime(14559):    at android.app.Activity.requestWindowFeature(Activity.java:3244)
05-31 04:20:43.121: E/AndroidRuntime(14559):    at matt.lyons.bibletrivia.lite.MainMenu.onCreate(MainMenu.java:28)
05-31 04:20:43.121: E/AndroidRuntime(14559):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
05-31 04:20:43.121: E/AndroidRuntime(14559):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
05-31 04:20:43.121: E/AndroidRuntime(14559):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
05-31 04:20:43.121: E/AndroidRuntime(14559):    ... 11 more
```

Comment: Can you elaborate?  I do not know what "through theme" means.

Comment: You can apply theme in Manifest under activity tag like, **android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"** instead writing java code in onCreate.

Answer (score 196, accepted):

I also faced this problem but when i call window request before calling **super.onCreate()** then problem was solved, please try it also like..

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.mainmenu);
}
```

Hope this will help you...:)

---

**Edited: For other possible solutions for Android'd new versions**

**Hide the Status Bar on Android 4.0 and Lower**

```
<application
    ...
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.NoActionBar.Fullscreen" >
    ...
</application>
```

The advantages of using an activity theme are as follows:

- It's easier to maintain and less error-prone than setting a flag programmatically.
- It results in smoother UI transitions, because the system has the information it needs to render your UI before instantiating your app's main activity.

---

**Android version is lower than Jellybean**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // If the Android version is lower than Jellybean, use this call to hide
    // the status bar.
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 16) {
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    }
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
```

---

**Hide the Status Bar on Android 4.1 and Higher**

```
View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
// Hide the status bar.
int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);
// Remember that you should never show the action bar if the
// status bar is hidden, so hide that too if necessary.
ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
actionBar.hide();
```

Note the following:

- Once UI flags have been cleared (for example, by navigating away from the activity), your app needs to reset them if you want to hide the bars again. See [Responding to UI Visibility Changes](http://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/visibility.html) for a discussion of how to listen for UI visibility changes so that your app can respond accordingly.
- Where you set the UI flags makes a difference. If you hide the system bars in your activity's onCreate() method and the user presses Home, the system bars will reappear. When the user reopens the activity, onCreate() won't get called, so the system bars will remain visible. If you want system UI changes to persist as the user navigates in and out of your activity, set UI flags in onResume() or onWindowFocusChanged().
- The method setSystemUiVisibility() only has an effect if the view you call it from is visible.
- Navigating away from the view causes flags set with setSystemUiVisibility() to be cleared.

Comment: @clu This **requestFeature (int featureId)** must be called before setContentView(). May be called as many times as desired as long as it is before setContentView(). If not called, no extended features will be available. You can not turn off a feature once it is requested. [For more detail click here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Window.html#requestFeature(int))

Comment: I would advise against calling `requestWindowFeature` before `super.onCreate`. You can't be sure about the state of the Activity before that point.

Comment: @vishesh chandra
can you help in my case this is not worked for me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27404146/when-orientation-changed-i-got-requestfeature-must-be-called-before-adding-con

Comment: Solved the problem, but the title bar still appears.

Comment: Yes, for me also the action bar still appears

Comment: I'm also facing the same issue. Even I tried but placing the line before the super.onCreate... My application didn't crash but there was no change. The action bar was still visible

Comment: To hide the action bar you can use **getActionbar().hide();** or **getActivity().getActionbar().hide();**.

Answer (score 14):

I got that exception (`android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: requestFeature() must be called before adding content`) when using

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

in an older device running Android 2.3.5 (Gingerbread). I am using the v7 support library.

The error was fixed when I changed it to use:

```
supportRequestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);
```

(This comes after my super.onCreate call in the fix, too). See docs at https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/ActionBarActivity.html#supportRequestWindowFeature(int)

So it may be more a case of a misleading error message than anything else.

Comment: Worked also for me. I'm using ActionBarActivity from the support library v21.

Comment: I'm using `appCompat` and so `supportRequestWindowFeature` did the trick for me and I didn't have to put it before `super.onCreate`

Comment: sure this used to work since this post is 5 years old, but just fyi: Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS is deprecated as of api vs. 24

Answer (score 7):

If you're using your activity as a Dialog (with Theme.Dialog), then make sure you extend Activity instead of ActionBarActivity (the default given to you with the Android Studio wizard). Then you can use

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

or

```
supportRequestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

AFTER the `super.onCreate()`...

Answer (score 7):

Please check your class is extend from Activity or ActionBarActivity. If you are using ActionBarActivity please use Activity.

Comment: This was my issue! I was extending AppCompatActivity and the requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE) was not successful in hiding the title bar until I switched to extending Activity.

Answer (score 3):

I also ran into this error from a different workflow. I created a custom DialogFragment class and I created two `@Override` functions - onCreateView and onCreateDialog. My onCreateView function grabbed a custom layout for the fragment, and my onCreateDialog function created an AlertDialog.Builder.

This appeared to not work because the onCreateDialog is called before onCreateView. After I deleted onCreateView [by moving my custom view inflation into onCreateDialog, i encountered the error:

`java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.`

I realized my difficulty came from trying to implement both overrides since I wanted to 1) use a layout for the main view of the dialog, and 2) use the Builder pre-defined Positive / Negative buttons. My solution was to create the positive / negative buttons in my custom dialog view, so i deleted my implementation of the Override onCreateDialog function.

Hope this helps someone in the future!

Here are some SO questions that helped me:

- [Problem inflating custom view for AlertDialog in DialogFragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7508185/problem-inflating-custom-view-for-alertdialog-in-dialogfragment)
- [ViewPager in DialogFragment - IllegalStateException: Fragment does not have a view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20303865/viewpager-in-dialogfragment-illegalstateexception-fragment-does-not-have-a-vi)
- [Custom Layout for DialogFragment OnCreateView vs. OnCreateDialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13257038/custom-layout-for-dialogfragment-oncreateview-vs-oncreatedialog)
- [The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19301458/the-specified-child-already-has-a-parent-you-must-call-removeview-on-the-chil)

Answer (score 2):

I was extending a **DialogFragment** and the above answer didnot work. I had to use getDialog() to remove the title:

```
getDialog().getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

Answer (score 2):

```html
 <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>

    </style>
```

just only set style like this no any coding side changing is required.

Answer (score 1):

Extend (**Activity**) instead of (**ActionBarActivity**)

example: `public class Itemdetails extends Activity {....`

then in the onCreate write:

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
setContentView(R.layout.Your_Activity);
```

Answer (score 1):

Misplaced your line:
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

use this Manner:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_qrscanner);
```

Answer (score 1):

I had this error with `AlertDialog` and the error was happening in API 19 only when `dialog.show()` was called.

figured out that the `android.app.AlertDialog` import is causing the problem so I changed it to `androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog` and it fixed it.

Note that this will work if you are using androidx. if you are not, you should use the old appcompat version of that import.

Answer (score 0):

i think the simplest way to do this is use this below code

```
  getActionBar().setTitle(null);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following options, at least one of these should work for you:

1. If you are using a DialogFragment then try not overriding both methods `onCreateDialog(..)` and `onCreateView(..)`  (This change worked for me)
2. try `supportRequestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE)/requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE)` before `setContentView(..)` in the activity and after `super.onCreate(..);`
3. Try option 2 before `super.onCreate(..);`