# My app is crashing after installing the MonkeyTalk agent

Tags: android, maven, aspectj, monkeytalk, aspectj-maven-plugin

I'm trying to use the [MonkeyTalk](https://www.gorillalogic.com/monkeytalk) to automate the black-box tests in my Android app. The problem I'm facing is that they don't have anything documented about using it with Maven. So, after a lot of research and trying a lot of things, I made the build to work. But, my app  is crashing when I install the MonkeyTalk agent.

I don't know if it's something wrong with my build or if the MonkeyTalk agent is incompatible with the libraries I'm using. So, here is what I've done to build with maven:

First, I've downloaded the MonkeyTalk and installed the JAR of the agent using this command:

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=monkeytalk-agent-1.0.53.jar -DgroupId="com.gorillalogic.monkeytalk" -DartifactId="monkeytalk-agent" -Dversion="1.0.53" -Dpackaging="jar"
```

So, I added the following dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
    <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.2</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
    <artifactId>aspectjtools</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.2</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

And, since I don't want the MonkeyTalk agent to be included in every release, I've created a profile as follows:

```
<profile>
    <id>monkeytalk</id>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.gorillalogic.monkeytalk</groupId>
            <artifactId>monkeytalk-agent</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.53</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                    <aspectLibraries>
                        <aspectLibrary>
                            <groupId>com.gorillalogic.monkeytalk</groupId>
                            <artifactId>monkeytalk-agent</artifactId>
                        </aspectLibrary>
                    </aspectLibraries>
                    <showWeaveInfo>true</showWeaveInfo>
                    <verbose>true</verbose>
                    <Xlint>ignore</Xlint>
                    <outxml>true</outxml>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <!--<phase>process-sources</phase>-->
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                            <goal>test-compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</profile>
```

With this configuration, the build works normally. I see in the log that the aspectj plugin is configuring the MonkeyTalk. Here is part of the log:

```
[INFO] Join point 'method-call(void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence))' in Type 'com.devspark.appmsg.AppMsg' (AppMsg.java:144) advised by before advice from 'com.gorillalogic.fonemonkey.aspects.SetText' (monkeytalk-agent-1.0.56.jar!SetText.class:26(from SetText.aj))
[INFO] Join point 'method-call(void com.devspark.appmsg.AppMsg.setText(java.lang.CharSequence))' in Type 'com.devspark.appmsg.AppMsg' (AppMsg.java:286) advised by before advice from 'com.gorillalogic.fonemonkey.aspects.SetText' (monkeytalk-agent-1.0.56.jar!SetText.class:26(from SetText.aj))
[INFO] Join point 'method-call(void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence))' in Type 'com.devspark.appmsg.AppMsg' (AppMsg.java:302) advised by before advice from 'com.gorillalogic.fonemonkey.aspects.SetText' (monkeytalk-agent-1.0.56.jar!SetText.class:26(from SetText.aj))
```

Ok, but when I install the app and try to open it, I can only open the first screen, that is the most simple, having just some buttons that either login via a social network or open another Activity. But when I open another Activity, that is much more complex, the app crashes. And it's very strange, because in each Android version, it crashes with a different exception.

This exception, for example, happens with Android 4.3:

```
08-22 16:49:54.012: INFO/ActivityManager(534): START u0 {cmp=com.soongz/.ui.CadastroActivity} from pid 17633
08-22 16:49:54.803: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(17633): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.soongz/com.soongz.ui.CadastroActivity}: android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: requestFeature() must be called before adding content
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
        Caused by: android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: requestFeature() must be called before adding content
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.requestFeature(PhoneWindow.java:226)
        at android.app.Activity.requestWindowFeature(Activity.java:3264)
        at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.supportRequestWindowFeature(ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.java:126)
        at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.supportRequestWindowFeature(ActionBarActivity.java:150)
        at com.soongz.ui.BaseActionBarActivity.createView(BaseActionBarActivity.java:72)
        at com.soongz.ui.CadastroActivity.createView(CadastroActivity.java:110)
        at br.com.cybereagle.androidlibrary.ui.helper.RetainedActivityHelper.onCreate(RetainedActivityHelper.java:42)
        at br.com.cybereagle.androidlibrary.ui.RetainedRoboActionBarActivity.onCreate(RetainedRoboActionBarActivity.java:45)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175)
        ... 11 more
08-22 16:49:54.813: WARN/ActivityManager(534): Force finishing activity com.soongz/.ui.CadastroActivity
08-22 16:49:54.813: WARN/ActivityManager(534): Force finishing activity com.soongz/.ui.MainActivity
```

In Android 2.2, I have this exception:

```
08-22 17:32:32.503: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(698): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.gorillalogic.fonemonkey.automators.AutomationManager
        at com.gorillalogic.fonemonkey.aspects.SetListener.ajc$after$com_gorillalogic_fonemonkey_aspects_SetListener$1$bfeaeda5(SetListener.aj:30)
        at com.soongz.service.autenticacao.AbstractAutenticador.<init>(AbstractAutenticador.java:51)
        at com.soongz.service.autenticacao.AutenticadorFacebook.<init>(AutenticadorFacebook.java:38)
        at com.soongz.ui.MainActivity.initializeUnretainedInstanceFields(MainActivity.java:54)
        at br.com.cybereagle.androidlibrary.ui.helper.RetainedActivityHelper.onCreate(RetainedActivityHelper.java:34)
        at br.com.cybereagle.androidlibrary.ui.RetainedRoboFragmentActivity.onCreate(RetainedRoboFragmentActivity.java:36)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Does someone with more experience with MonkeyTalk knows why its agent is breaking my app? Is it my maven configuration?

Answer (score 1):

If requestFeature is optional, try removing the line of code.

Or put the line of code above super.onCreate() as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16939814/android-util-androidruntimeexception-requestfeature-must-be-called-before-add) says.

[This blog](http://bugreporter.blogspot.jp/2013/11/monkeytalk-seems-not-to-support.html) may be mentioning the same problem.