# The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-intent

I am doing a little exercise about a application you that put your name, and it returns "hello (the name you put)". But after i push the button i get the error "The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first"

**MainActivity.java**

```java
package com.example.holaamigos;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.*;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    public final static String EXTRA_SALUDO = "com.example.holaamigos.SALUDO";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        
        final EditText txtNombre = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.TxtNombre);
        final Button btnHola = (Button)findViewById(R.id.BtnHola);
            
            btnHola.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ActivitySaludo.class);
                    String saludo = txtNombre.getText().toString();
                    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_SALUDO, saludo);
                    startActivity(intent);
        }
                
    });
            
    }
                    
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

**ActivitySaludo.java**

```java
package com.example.holaamigos;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class ActivitySaludo extends Activity {
    
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_saludo);
        
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String saludo = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_SALUDO);
        
        //TextView txt = new TextView(this);
        //txt.setText(20);
        //txt.setText(saludo);
        
        TextView txtCambiado = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TxtSaludo);
        txtCambiado.setText(saludo);
        setContentView(txtCambiado);
    }

}
```

**activity_saludo.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    
    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/TxtSaludo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="" />
    

</LinearLayout>
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/LblNombre"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/nombre" />
    
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/TxtNombre"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="text" />
    
    <Button 
        android:id="@+id/BtnHola"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hola_apy"
        android:onClick="enviarSaludo"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

**LogCat**

```java
10-10 16:12:18.470: D/AndroidRuntime(810): Shutting down VM
10-10 16:12:18.470: W/dalvikvm(810): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)
10-10 16:12:18.586: E/AndroidRuntime(810): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-10 16:12:18.586: E/AndroidRuntime(810): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.holaamigos/com.example.holaamigos.ActivitySaludo}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
10-10 16:12:18.586: E/AndroidRuntime(810):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
10-10 16:12:18.586: E/AndroidRuntime(810):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
10-10 16:12:18.586: E/AndroidRuntime(810):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
10-10 16:12:18.586: E/AndroidRuntime(810):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
10-10 16:12:18.586: E/AndroidRuntime(810):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-10 16:12:18.586: E/AndroidRuntime(810):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-10 16:12:18.586: E/AndroidRuntime(810):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
10-10 16:12:18.586: E/AndroidRuntime(810):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-10 16:12:18.586: E/AndroidRuntime(810):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-10 16:12:18.586: E/AndroidRuntime(810):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
10-10 16:12:18.586: E/AndroidRuntime(810):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
10-10 16:12:18.586: E/AndroidRuntime(810):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-10 16:12:18.586: E/AndroidRuntime(810): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
10-10 16:12:18.586: E/AndroidRuntime(810):  at android.view.ViewGroup.addViewInner(ViewGroup.java:3339)
10-10 16:12:18.586: E/AndroidRuntime(810):  at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3210)
10-10 16:12:18.586: E/AndroidRuntime(810):  at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3186)
10-10 16:12:18.586: E/AndroidRuntime(810):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:289)
10-10 16:12:18.586: E/AndroidRuntime(810):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:279)
10-10 16:12:18.586: E/AndroidRuntime(810):  at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1901)
10-10 16:12:18.586: E/AndroidRuntime(810):  at com.example.holaamigos.ActivitySaludo.onCreate(ActivitySaludo.java:25)
10-10 16:12:18.586: E/AndroidRuntime(810):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
10-10 16:12:18.586: E/AndroidRuntime(810):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
10-10 16:12:18.586: E/AndroidRuntime(810):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
10-10 16:12:18.586: E/AndroidRuntime(810):  ... 11 more
10-10 16:12:18.856: D/dalvikvm(810): GC_CONCURRENT freed 134K, 10% free 2630K/2908K, paused 73ms+83ms, total 237ms
```

Comment: You should select the accepted answer.

Answer (score 131):

I encountered this error whenever I omitted a parameter while inflating the view for a fragment in the `onCreateView()` method like so:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_reject, container);
    return view;
}
```

The solution is to change the view inflation line to:

`View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_reject, container,false);`

The explanation can be found at the [Android guide for fragments](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html)

Quoting from the guide, the final parameter in the view initialization statement is false because:

> "the system is already inserting the inflated layout into the container—passing true would create a redundant view group in the final layout"

Comment: It seems many people got this error while using fragment , though OP's questions' context is different .

Comment: Thanks buddy `View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_reject, container,false);` did the trick

Answer (score 28):

In onCreate with activity or onCreateView with fragment

```
 if (view != null) {
    ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) view.getParent();
    if (parent != null) {
        parent.removeView(view);
    }
}
try {
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
} catch (InflateException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: You are not far off, indeed reinflating an existing View causes that crash. You are correct. HOWEVER, according to this: http://android-developers.blogspot.co.uk/2009/01/avoiding-memory-leaks.html , you should not keep a reference to a view in the first place!!! So just inflate every time and delete the view member !

Comment: the first part of the fix seems to work quite well, was searching for a solution for some time (not using layouts in my case)

Comment: this is great if you want to keep a view alive for the life of the app and keep adding it and removing from layouts - i.e. for when you have a view that takes a while to initialize.

Answer (score 20):

in `ActivitySaludo`, this line,

```
    setContentView(txtCambiado);
```

you must set the content view for the activity only once.

Answer (score 10):

You dont need this line: `setContentView(txtCambiado);`

Answer (score 5):

In my case I was accidentally returning a child view from within `Layout.onCreateView()` as shown below:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_reject, container, false);

    Button button = view.findViewById(R.id.some_button);

    return button; // <-- Problem is this
}
```

The solution was to return the parent view instead of the child view.

Comment: I was using databinding and did not realize I was not returning the root view. This answer helped me so much!

Answer (score 2):

In my case the problem was I was trying to add same view multiple times to linear layout

```
View childView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.lay_progressheader, parentLayout,false);

 for (int i = 1; i <= totalCount; i++) {

     parentLayout.addView(childView);

 }
```

just initialize view every time to fix the issue

```
 for (int i = 1; i <= totalCount; i++) {

     View childView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.lay_progressheader, parentLayout,false);

      parentLayout.addView(childView);

 }
```

Answer (score 1):

**Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.**

```
TextView textView = new TextView(this);
textView.setText("CustomTextView");
addContentView(textView,new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

Comment: It is better to have explanation to your answer.

Comment: addContentView() insted to setContentView, bcz setContentView it's override ur xml all view and i think u want to just add run time textview in ur already define xml...

Answer (score 1):

if you are adding the same view repeatedly in a for loop .. if this is the case then try creating the View object of the layout inside the for loop . 
and add the view in side the for loop

To avoid such issues

Comment: Could you please elaborate more on this ?

Comment: for(int i = 0 ; i < x ; i++){
View v = create / inflate the view 
ll.addView(v);      // every time the loop is created we need to create a new view  which has to be added/ inflated to a empty linear layout . 
if you try to create the View outside the loop then and add that same view repetedly to the linear layout then an exceptionwill be raised asking you to remove the child from parent before adding a new one 

}

** if this is the issue then the answer is this  . i dnt know if its a way around if their any other official better solution , this is what i do 

Hope it helps you

Comment: Thanks for this answer, it fixed the error in my app.

Answer (score 1):

I’ve found a solution. I had to clear fragment’s parent from views before destroying and I’ve used the next peace of code for this:

in Java

```
public void onDestroyView() {
        if (rootView != null){
            ViewGroup viewGroup = (ViewGroup)rootView.getParent();
            if (viewGroup != null){
                viewGroup.removeAllViews();
            }
        }
        super.onDestroyView();
    }
```

in Kotlin

```
override fun onDestroyView() {
    if (rootView != null) {
        val viewGroup = rootView.parent as ViewGroup?
        viewGroup?.removeAllViews();
    }
    super.onDestroyView()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case i just pass the wrong `view` to the Method

Answer (score 0):

You just need to initialize your view in onCreate() method and then in onCreateDialog() again before setView() and it should be work!

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this error while there is an invisible view in an activity xml layout. At that time it was not used in my case so I have removed it and the crash is not seen anymore.

Answer (score 0):

frameLayout.addView(yourView); <----- if you are getting error on this line remove view from it's parent first

if (yourView.getParent() != null)

((ViewGroup) yourView.getParent()).removeView(yourView);
frameLayout.addView(yourView); (Add view to layout)

Comment: when providing code as answer please describe how does this answer the question. Just code is not an answer.