# Adding ScrollView to existing XML Layout

Tags: android, xml, scrollview

I'm answering my own question because even though I figured it out, I wasn't able to get a clear solution. This may help someone else.

I know the exception I receive is a common one, but I couldn't solve my problem with the following pages:

[The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19301458/the-specified-child-already-has-a-parent-you-must-call-removeview-on-the-chil)
[java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10007094/java-lang-illegalstateexception-the-specified-child-already-has-a-parent)
[Call removeView() on the child's parent first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6526874/call-removeview-on-the-childs-parent-first)
http://www.phonesdevelopers.com/1716777/

What I want to do it add a bunch of `TextView`s to a `ScrollView`, and then put the `ScrollView` on the screen. The problem is that the `ScrollView` is only part of the screen, so I can't just use `setContentView(scrollView)` because that would replace the buttons and things I already have.

I have an XML file that contains the template for my layout, and I simply want to replace the `ScrollView` with the one I generated in my Activity.

Here is the layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/mostParent" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/loadingPanel"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center" >

        <ProgressBar
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:indeterminate="true" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnLogout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="@string/logout" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/refresh"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_action_refresh" />

    <ToggleButton
        android:id="@+id/lockToggle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text=""
        android:textOff="@string/toggle_off"
        android:textOn="@string/toggle_on" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/loggedInAs"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/refresh"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text=""
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/postsView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/btnLogout"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:scrollbarSize="3dip" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

The `ScrollView` at the bottom is the one I want to add the `TextView`s to and it has the id `postsView`.

So I'm going to create a `LinearLayout`, add the `TextView`s to that layout, and then add that layout to the `ScrollView`. Like this:

```java
ScrollView postsView = (ScrollView)findViewById(R.id.postsView);

LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(MyActivity.this);
layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

for (final TextView post : posts) {
    // add post to layout
    layout.addView(post);
}

postsView.addView(layout);
```

But with this, I get the LogCat:

```java
java.lang.IllegalStateException: ScrollView can host only one direct child
```

How can I remove the view from the `ScrollView`?

Comment: so do you just want to add scrollview to xml, is that all??

Comment: @DushyantPatel Yes. The reason it was difficult was because I was adding the layout I created to *two* ScrollViews (for testing purposes), so I was getting an unexpected error. Then I found out the only real problem was that I was adding too many views and not removing them each time. Problem solved, I answered my own question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`removeAllViews()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#removeAllViews%28%29) on the `ScrollView`. This is happening because whenever the code is being run more than once, more than one view is being added to the `ScrollView`.

Your code would change this:

```java
postsView.addView(layout);
```

To:

```java
postsView.removeAllViews()
postsView.addView(layout);
```