# calling requestWindowFeature() after onCreate()

Tags: android

As mentioned in several [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16939962/1869297), calling `requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE)` should be before `super.onCreate(...)` and `setContentView(...)`.
However, I want the screen's title to appear when the activity is created, and to disappear only **after** returning from another activity.
I tried this:

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    switch (requestCode) {
    case REQUEST_CONNECT_DEVICE: 
            requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    }
}
```

And I'm getting the `android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: requestFeature() must be called before adding content` exception.

Comment: and you are getting the right exception... it works that way

Comment: of course, I'm asking how to disappear the title **after** the `onCreate(...)` was called.

Comment: By title do you mean actionbar? If so you can use getActionBar.hide()/show() methods.

Comment: Great, that solves the problem :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// try this way,hope this will help you....

Note : i think what you trying do is not possible so try this alternative.
public class FirstActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        if(!getIntent().getBooleanExtra("isTitleShow",true)){
            requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        }
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // this condition for stop to call SecondActivity after one time call
        if(getIntent().getBooleanExtra("isTitleShow",true)){
            Intent intent = new Intent(this,SecondActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }
    }
} 


public class SecondActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Intent intent = new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("isTitleShow",false);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```