# Unable to hide action bar

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I tried to create a new Android application and I tried to hide the action bar in the constructor of MainActivity, using the line `requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);`

I've done this previously many times and there wasn't any problem in this. But when I try the same now it throws a error mentioning that "request feature must be called before adding the content"

Even I've tried adding this line in various positions but there wasn't any change in result. Can anyone help me solving this issue.

Comment: which theme you are using?

Comment: call it before calling setContentView

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16939814/android-util-androidruntimeexception-requestfeature-must-be-called-before-add

Comment: Theme.AppCompat.Light

this is one which is showing in my manifest, also I dont remember the one which I selected when I created the project

Comment: Yes, I've tried calling this line everywhere like before and after setContentView, super.onCreate...  But there wasn't any change

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two ways to hide `actionbar`. I am assuming you are using `Theme.AppCompat.Light` style and your activity `extends ActionBarActivity`.

Set below lines to your styles.xml

```
 <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
```

Or

Set below lines in your java file.

`getSupportActionBar().hide();`

Comment: Thank you very much. this worked for me.
getSupportActionBar().hide();

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this:

```
getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
```

It should be called before setContentView() method in onCreate() method of Activity.

Answer (score 0):

You should add `requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);` before `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);`

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
```

Answer (score 0):

Put this after `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);`

```
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```