# Android action bar alternatives

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

I am working on an app right now whose blueprints I got from a friend. I offered to use the ActionBar for screen navigation, but he insists on a little red button at the top-right of the screen.
I have two question:

1. Having never designed in android, can I make the ActionBar completely transparent, except for a little red square on the right so it looks like what i described?
2. If there is not such way, can someone please offer an alternative? I was searching for "button drop down list", but got only very old tutorials. Maybe I should look for something else?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Yes, you can make the Action Bar transparent. There is an example: [Custom Translucent Android ActionBar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6749261/custom-translucent-android-actionbar). Of course, you can make completely transparant AB. Then you can add a `MenuItem` to the top-right corner (it will be your little red button).
   [Here](http://jgilfelt.github.io/android-actionbarstylegenerator/) you have an Android Action Bar Style Generator. As you can see, there is an option for solid or transparent Action Bar.
2. There is no need to break the rules with a proper navigation pattern (Action Bar).