# Setting a Transparent ActionBar Resulting in a White ActionBar

Tags: android, android-theme, android-layout-weight

I have an `Activity` where I would like to have it's `ActionBar` transparent.

I am using `API Level 18` and my Activity is an `AppCompatActivity`

I have tried many solutions on StackOverFlow but they dont seem to work

This is the latest one I tried

```
<!-- Application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme.TransparentActionBar" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>

    <!-- Support library compatibility -->
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
</style>

<!-- ACTION BAR STYLES -->
<style name="MyActionBar" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>

    <!-- Support library compatibility -->
    <item name="background">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
</style>
```

It simply turned the `ActionBar` to white. All solutions I've came up with turns the `ActionBar` to white.

Any thoughts?

I have also tried this code

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR_OVERLAY);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

}
```

My `activity_login.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:background="@color/colorYellow"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".LoginActivity">

</RelativeLayout>
```

### EDIT

Actually the `ActionBar` is transparent. But the contentView itself is not underneath it. How can I possibly place the contentView underneath the `ActionBar`?

Comment: you code is working fine... and what is your activity_login page background color.

Comment: Notice: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1492554/set-transparent-background-of-an-imageview-in-android

Comment: Check this[link](http://androhub.com/android-toolbar-animation-using-design-support-library/).

Comment: and this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11285961/how-to-make-a-background-transparent-20-in-android

Comment: use yellow it self as actionbar background or with opacity - as suggested in above comments..

Comment: @bharat Actually you were right. The `ActionBar` IS transparent. but the problem is, it is not on top of the `contentView`. How can I place it underneath the ActionBar?

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution, it is a answer by this [guy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31076942/2224226)

This is for `AppCompatActivity`

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    supportRequestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR_OVERLAY);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public void setTransparentStatusBar() {
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {

            Window window = getWindow();
            if (window != null) {
                window.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS,
                        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);

                window.getAttributes().flags &= (~WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
            }
            window.setStatusBarColor(Color.parseColor("#00000000"));

        }
    }
```

Call this in `onCreate()` of the activity! It worked for me, I hope this helps!